# Is everything a pointer in LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I iterate through the global vars of the program and am interested for their types.

For a test, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i=0;
int main(){
    printf("lala %d \n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

What I get on the output is:

```
Globals: 
i Type: 14  //14 ==> POINTER TYPE ID !
StackLock: Stack1 
Function Argument: i32* @i
```

My code:

```
for (Module::global_iterator I = M.global_begin(), E = M.global_end(); I != E; ++I) {
            std::cout << I->getName().str() << " Type: "<< I->getType()->getTypeID() << std::endl;

            if (I->getType()->isPointerTy() ) {
                std::string o1;
                {
                    raw_string_ostream os1(o1);
                    I->printAsOperand(os1, true);
                }
                char* stackLoc = new char[50];
                sprintf(stackLoc, "Stack%d", StackCounter++);
                errs() << "StackLock: " << stackLoc << "\n";
                errs() << "Function Argument: " << o1 << "\n";
            }

        }
```

What's the meaning of setting everything as pointers?
Is there any way to take the 'real' type? e.g on my example: to get the Integer Type for i variable.

Comment: Try printing the assembly generated by Clang. You'll see that global variables are all memory regions accessed via pointers, as are most local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [LLVM IR Reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#global-variables), Global variables define regions of memory allocated at compilation time instead of run-time, and they must be initialized.

> As SSA values, global variables define pointer values that are in
>   scope (i.e. they dominate) all basic blocks in the program. Global
>   variables always define a pointer to their “content” type because they
>   describe a region of memory, and all memory objects in LLVM are
>   accessed through pointers.

To get the actual type of your global variable, since the global variable's LLVM IR internal type is pointer, the `Type::getContainedType(int)` or `Type::getPointerElementType()` could be used to get the pointee type of the pointer, since pointer type is a derived type.